# The derivative of constant raised to the power of n which is raised to a constant

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I need a reminder of how to go about taking the derivative of $c^{n^x}$ where $x$ and $c$ are constants. An example would be

> $$\large 4^{n^2}$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So $n$ is a continuous variable?

Comment: Hint: think of how to use chain rule here. Also $d(a^x)=\ln(a)a^xdx$, for constant $a$ and variable $x$.

Comment: A better choice for the naming of the variables would be $a^{x^b}$; $n$ usually denotes a natural.

Answer (score 1):

You can write $4^{n^2} = e^{n^2\ln4}$ and then go at it with a chain rule, getting $(2n\ln{4})e^{n^2 \ln 4}$

Answer (score 1):

You first differentiate the exponential using the rule $(a^f)'=\log a\,a^f f'$,

$$\left(a^{x^b}\right)'=\log a\,a^{x^b}\left({x^b}\right)'$$

then expand the derivative of the power,

$$\left(a^{x^b}\right)'=\log a\,a^{x^b}b\,x^{b-1}.$$

---

Alternatively, you can use the so-called logarithmic derivative, using the rule

$$(\log g)'=\frac{g'}g\iff g'=g\;(\log g)'.$$

Then

$$\left(a^{x^b}\right)'=a^{x^b}\left(\log a^{x^b}\right)'=a^{x^b}\left(x^b\log a\right)'=a^{x^b}b\,x^{b-1}\log a.$$